# How do I send multiple SMS messages to unique phone numbers?

Tags: php, twilio

When I'm iterating the numbers in my database it won't send multiple text messages.

I've tried using a variable where the phone number is, but it keeps failing.

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $email = $row['email'];
            $phoneNum = $row['phone'];


                  $client = new Client($sid, $token);

                  // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
                  $client->messages->create(
                      // the number you'd like to send the message to
                      $phoneNum,
                      array(
                          // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
                          'from' => '+83939393',
                          // the body of the text message you'd like to send
                          'body' => 'The message'
                      )
                  );


      }
```

Comment: So how is it failing?

Comment: What error do you get? Is there anything more you can tell us about it?

Comment: The error was it wasn't sending more than one message. The code above does send to all phone numbers in db.  The problem was sending an email inside that same while loop which would make another query to a separate table to append into the body. I moved the query outside of the first while loop and now twilio will send all SMS's to each phone number along with the other data I wanted to get from a different table. So if any one else experiences it not sending to all numbers in a database - see if you can minimize your while loop to not make other queries inside.

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 //All that needed to be done is move problem query out of this while loop into its own.


// moved to here

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

          $email = $row['email'];
          $phoneNum = $row['phone'];

          $to = $email;

          $message.= "
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>Email</title>
                </head>
                <body>

                <h1>Data I wanted to show in email</h1>";
                 // problem query below

                  $message.= "<ul>";
                  // moved $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT query here";
                  $result = $db->query($sql);
                  $countUrl = 0;
                  $message .= "<ul>";
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {

                   $message .= "<li><a href=".$row['url'].">". $row['url']."</a></li>";


                }

                $message .= "</ul>"; 
                $message .= "</li>";
               // moved this outside the while loop and everything was fine.

                $message .="


                </div>


                </body>
                </html>
                ";
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: no-repley@blah.com' . "\r\n" .
                 'Reply-To: ' . $e_ . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                $headers .= 'From: name' . "\r\n";

           if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
              echo "success mailed to ".$to;

                  $client = new Client($sid, $token);

                  // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
                  $client->messages->create(
                      // the number you'd like to send the message to
                      $phoneNum,
                      array(
                          // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
                          'from' => '+83838388',
                          // the body of the text message you'd like to send
                          'body' => '$url variables from that query'
                      )
                  );

           }

        }

      }
  }else{
     echo "no emails set";
  }

}
```